# Strange behavior in Windows Forms application running at different DPI settings

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, scaling, dpi

I have a Windows Forms application (written in vs2010/C# against .NET framework 3.5) with one main form. It was designed at Win7's 100% DPI setting (I believe that's 96 dpi). When switching the computer to 150%, everything appears to scale just fine and all proportions are kept.

However, when I switch to 125%, some of the controls suddenly don't scale and appear to be as big as they would be at 100%. This messes up the whole layout, and hides some controls from the user.

Is there any kind of logical explanation as to the large difference in behavior between the 125% and 150% settings?

Also, is there a quicker way to test this? Having to log off and back in again every time I switch is quickly becoming annoying.

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple explanation for what you observe.

A cheap way to test this without having to go through the painful login cycle is to change the form's Font property in the OnLoad method:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.SizeInPoints * 120f / 96f);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: It most certainly should, try it on a little test project.  That you don't see an effect in your form ought to be the reason you got trouble making it work properly.

Comment: Another way to test this is to have multiple Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 2):

Look at form's [AutoScaleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode.aspx).  It is probably set to Font or Dpi

Comment: Sure, that's what makes it scale.

Comment: It was set to Font. I changed it to Dpi, but that didn't appear to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add to John Arlen's post:

You may also want to allow the form to Grow and Shrink, using the [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729.aspx).

Comment: The form grows and scales properly. Some controls on it don't. I'll expand my question to include which types of controls those are.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to "Also, is there a quicker way to test this? Having to log off and back in again every time I switch is quickly becoming annoying."

Best thing is to use a Virtual Machine with a different DPI settings. 
You just run your application from the 'real' machine.